# Equivalent of `Column(verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up)` when using a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like a ListView where the first item in the list is sorted on top, with the seconds item sorted next, etc.

This is doable with Column() doing something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = [
      Container(height: 60, width: double.infinity, color: Colors.amber),
      Transform.translate(
        offset: const Offset(0, -50),
        child: Container(height: 60, width: double.infinity, color: Colors.green)),
    ];
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
        children: items.reversed.toList());
  }
```

This will cause the first item (Amber) to render on top of the 2nd: [image]

Normally, with code like `Column(children: items)` the green would render on top of the amber, like so:

[image]

I would like to do the former example, but using a ListView.

Comment: The order of items is by default first item is on top, then second item below, etc. What you want to achieve is already by default when using ListView is it?

Comment: It is the sort-order I am referring too, not the position in the list. I need the first item to be sorted on top. By default the first item ends up sorted last. ie, if Item1 and Item2 overlap, Item2 will be on top, I need Item1 on top.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue and the result you are trying to archive?

Comment: I've update the question to provide a more concrete code example.

Can think of it as a `ListView` with reverse sorting order (not layout order, just sorting). This is all so that some hero animations will look correct if you're wondering.

Comment: @shawnblais is this similar usage not working for your case? ```ListView(children: items.reversed.toList())```